# Incorporating a table inside a table in HTML

Tags: html, html-table, jinja2

I am trying to create an HTML table where there are four columns and any number of rows. Inside this table, the first two columns are just normal cells. The latter two columns can have multiple rows WITHIN a row in the top-level table. My issue is how I can properly align the column separators, even if the length of the content in each cell is variable.

My attempt tries to make use of:

```
<td colspan=2>
```

Example of what I am trying to do: https://jsfiddle.net/hurnzhmq/

The things I am missing in the JSFiddle are:

1. There is no divider between the two rows separating Content3A/Content4A from Content3B/Content4B - I tried using the "bottom-border:none" for the last child, but that did not seem to work.
2. The column separators between Content3A/Content3B and Content4A/Content4B are not lined up with the header's column separator, and do not touch the ends of the table (there are gaps).

Any advice on how I might go about fixing this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you past you exact code? Or it is the ones from jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use rowspan instead colspan
you can use code below

```
 <html>


     <table border=1 >

      <tr>
      <td>Header1</td>
      <td>Header2</td>
      <td>Header3</td>
      <td>Header4</td>
      </tr>

      <!-- Content -->
       <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Content1</td>
      <td rowspan="2" >Content2</td>
      <td > Content3A</td>
      <td > Content2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>

      <td > Content3B</td>
      <td > Content2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </html>
```

Comment: Ok, so it is actually a little more complicated than I had previously explained - I am using Jinja2 (HTML templating), and am actually generating Content3A/3B/4A/4B using a for loop. That means that I would only have new <tr></tr> before the 2nd, 3rd,...,nth row. How would I be able to create these new rows, without creating a new row for the first pair?

In the case you have given, I would need <tr></tr> for Content3B/Content2, but not for Content3A/Content2

Comment: dear James, I am not familiar with Jinja2 but I know that first you should create your Table use your loop then Use "if " for give condition for rowspan.